# sum row multiple variables

Tags: r, sum, line

I have the following structure for my dataset:

```
id amount zipcode cat1 cat1_times cat2 cat2_times
1  1000   1001      0       0        1      7
2  2000   1001      0       0        1      7
3  2300   1002      1       6        1      5
4  1500   1002      1       6        1      5
5  2700   1003      1       3        1      5
6  3400   1003      1       3        1      5
```

Cat1 is a binary variable that takes the value 1 if there is a building of category 1 in a certain zipcode. Cat1_times is the number of buildings of category 1 in a certain zipcode.
I want to calculate the total number of building (cat1 + cat2) for each line:

```
id amount zipcode cat1 cat1_times cat2 cat2_times total_times
1  1000   1001      0       0        1      7          7
2  2000   1001      0       0        1      7          7
3  2300   1002      1       6        1      5          11          
4  1500   1002      1       6        1      5          11
5  2700   1003      1       3        1      5          8
6  3400   1003      1       3        1      5          8
```

I tried with sum(cat1_times,cat2_times) but I got the same result for each line.

Comment: `df$total_times = df$cat1_times + df$cat2_times` should work.

Comment: So simply `df$cat1_times + df$cat2_times`??...

Comment: Thank you all, both methods works, do you know why the function sum() was not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively if you would have many columns

```
numberOfCategories=2
rowSums(df[,paste0('cat',1:numberOfCategories,'_times')])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `stringr` 's `str_detect` with `rowSums`

```
library(stringr)
df$Total=rowSums(df[,names(df)[str_detect(names(df),'times')]])
df
  id amount zipcode cat1 cat1_times cat2 cat2_times Total
1  1   1000    1001    0          0    1          7     7
2  2   2000    1001    0          0    1          7     7
3  3   2300    1002    1          6    1          5    11
4  4   1500    1002    1          6    1          5    11
5  5   2700    1003    1          3    1          5     8
6  6   3400    1003    1          3    1          5     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% select(matches("times")) %>% transmute(total_times=rowSums(.)) %>% bind_cols(df1,.)

#  id amount zipcode cat1 cat1_times cat2 cat2_times total_times
#1  1   1000    1001    0          0    1          7           7
#2  2   2000    1001    0          0    1          7           7
#3  3   2300    1002    1          6    1          5          11
#4  4   1500    1002    1          6    1          5          11
#5  5   2700    1003    1          3    1          5           8
#6  6   3400    1003    1          3    1          5           8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
df1$total_times <- Reduce(`+`, df1[grep('cat\\d+_times', names(df1))])
df1$total_times
#[1]  7  7 11 11  8  8
```